# How android bundle onListItemClick parameters with a list view

Tags: java, android

i got this

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myarray));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String gate = myarray[position];

        try {
            Class<?> inst;
            inst = Class.forName("com.example.killtheviolence.myapplication." + gate);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, inst);
            startActivity(intent);

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

how android known that this

> ListView l, View v, int position, long id

came from this

> setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter....

and the parameters are generated by android or i have to put anything in there